# Running GAS on other non-limited services/terminals?

Tags: google-apps-script

I wrote a Google script and defined a time-based trigger, but I need my code to run every few minutes, say 15, and during that period, it needs to loop constantly *(I'm using it for an automatic ticker board. It fetches data from a spreadsheet every 15 minutes, and displays several tables of  that processed data in a loop every few seconds).* 
I keep getting "Service using too much computer time for one day" errors and "Exceeded maximum execution time" errors. Is there a way to make it work in Google? If not, can I run the code and the triggers somewhere else?

Comment: Using a webapp, you can refresh the page every X seconds/minutes using a loop to re-populate the page. [Google has extensive documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) on how to get it set up. it would also be helpful to see what code you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, have you looked at the [limitations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)? Seems like you want the script to actually run for 15 minutes which directly clashes with the maximum 6 minute runtime of a script.

Furthermore, you would quite possibly hit the 1-hour total trigger runtime per day.

If you want, you can just have Javascript code run locally on your server and do Google API calls to get the google documents.